# Assigning callback value to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm using the package WordPos which has a function getNouns such that getNouns(text, callback), for example.

```
wordpos.getNouns('The angry bear chased the frightened little squirrel.', 
console.log)
// [ 'bear', 'squirrel', 'little', 'chased' ]
```

I want to write the promise to an array rather than logging it and haven't had any luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: do you want to use the array in a function or you specifically want to use promises to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "write the promise to an array"

Comment: What have you tried? Replacing console.log with a function that pushes to an array isn't working?

Comment: I want to use that array later on, or add those values to a set. I'm not well versed in promises so I don't know how to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do

```
wordpos.getNouns('The angry bear chased the frightened little squirrel.', result => {
  const array = result;
  // do stuff with `array`
})
```

Comment: Is there any way to use this array outside of this call?

Comment: Not unless you use Promises or async functions

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap this function with a `Promise`.

```
function getNounsPromise(string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    wordpos.getNouns(string, resolve);
  });
} 

// usage:
getNounsPromise('The angry bear chased the frightened little squirrel.')
  .then(result => console.log(result)); // [ 'bear', 'squirrel', 'little', 'chased' ]
```

Comment: So is it incorrect to do this:
    var result = getNounsPromise(string).then(result => console.log(result));
if I want to use result as the array?

Comment: this is not how asynchronous programming work

Comment: You can't serialize a promise.

Comment: I figured it out. I read up on promises and async, I do all of the things I need with the variable inside the callback function. Thanks for your help everyone!